# Broadcast receiver is not stopping

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

i am working on an app that will automatically decline incoming calls from specific numbers and send an sms in return.my broadcast receiver should be enabled from my app only.
so, i added ( android:enabled="false" ) this. but, the receiver is still on by default. i'm struck here.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.sifydy.automsgr.Automsgr"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.sifydy.automsgr.Receiver"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:enabled="false">

       <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
       </intent-filter>
       </receiver>
 </application>
```

wen i switch on my mobile, my receiver is also activated wen ever there is an incoming call.
i am able disable it from my app. everything is fine once i am in my app. how to disble it by default?

Comment: did you clean+refresh your project?

Comment: uninstall existing apk and install again.let me know if it works,i will make it as answer.

Comment: Thanks guys. i uninstalled the existing apk and installed it again. it worked like a charm. i have been hitting my monitor for hours but the answer was very simple. thank you so much Mehul joisar.